# Pyqt5 window open in secondary display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have below code to open pyqt5 in secondary display although `print` gives secondary screen resolution, but opening in first display where is my fault?

```
a = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = App()

# screen_count = a.desktop().screenCount()
screen_resolution = a.desktop().screenGeometry(1)
window_width = screen_resolution.width()
window_height = screen_resolution.height()
print(window_width,window_height) # it gives me secondary window res
x = (screen_resolution.width() - window_width) / 2
y = (screen_resolution.height() - window_height) / 2
w.move(x, y)
w.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation is wrong: `window_width` is equal to `screen_resolution.width()` (and the same goes for the height), so `x` and `y` will always be 0.

Besides, it doesn't consider the origin of the screen, so it's always based on `(0, 0)` even if the screen starts from another x or y.

Also, [`desktop()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication-obsolete.html#desktop) is obsolete, and you should use [`QGuiApplication.screens()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screens).

Finally, top level widgets have a default size of 640x480 (unless a minimum and/or maximum size has been specified), while you should use their [`sizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizeHint-prop) instead if available (eg. when the widget is a container and has a layout set).

```py
screen_resolution = a.screens()[1].availableGeometry()
window_size = w.sizeHint() or w.size()
window_width = window_size.width()
window_height = window_size.height()
x = screen_resolution.x() + (screen_resolution.width() - window_width) / 2
y = screen_resolution.y() + (screen_resolution.height() - window_height) / 2
w.move(x, y)
w.show()
```

Using QRect helper functions it's even easier:

```py
geo = QRect(QPoint(), w.sizeHint() or w.size())
geo.moveCenter(a.screens()[1].availableGeometry().center())
w.setGeometry(geo)
w.show()
```